# let c be a k cube, prove that there exists no k+1 chain b such that $\partial b = c$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

There is a former question says we can define the boundary of b as a certain linear combination of k-cubes, $\partial b = \sum_i a_i c_i$, prove $\sum_i a_i = 0$, where $c_i$ are k-cubes, if I can show this, then it follows that $\partial b$ cannot be a cube, but I have no idea how to show $\sum_i a_i = 0$.
    And I know the boundary of boundary is 0, so if $\partial b = c$, then $\partial c = 0$, which means $\int_c da = \int_{\partial c} a = 0$ for any k-1 form a, and how can I make a contradiction from here. Thank you for any help.

Comment: It would really help to give a link to this earlier question....

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Emm, the earlier question is also in the book Manifolds and Differential Forms together with this question and not on the website, sorry for my inaccurate expression